# Why an embeded swf won't play on a page under https?

Tags: flash, https

I have one swf banner which I want it into .aspx page. The website runs ok under http and the banner plays correctly. After we set the website to run under https, the banner stopped to load. 
I've tried to load this banner via http link from inside https running page. Nothing happened as well.

Example:
Page: https://www.myswebsite.com.br/default.aspx

Script inside:

```
 <script src="http://www.mywebsite.com.br/AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>   

    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="960" height="190" id="header" align="middle">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
        <param name="movie" value="header.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    
        <embed src="http://www.mywebsite.com.br/banner.swf" 
            quality="high" 
            bgcolor="#ffffff" 
            width="960" height="190" 
            name="header" 
            align="middle" 
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" 
            allowFullScreen="false"                 
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
    </noscript>
```

Comment: check your browser settings.. I believe IE has an option to not show insecure elements in a secure page

Answer (score 2):

Use relative URLs for your script source and embedded flash file. Then they will requested via the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) as the hosting page.

```
<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript" />
<embed src="banner.swf" ... />
```

[embed Tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp)

Comment: Sorry, change the ~ to .. or, since the movie is sitting in the same folder as your page (as it is in the example) just put the file name (banner.swf). See my updated answer for new code and a link.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's doesn't work too. I found out something about adobe security. Maybe the changes has to be in swf compilation. Not the application or server. We trying here...